# How can I boot ARM vm on x86 host with qemu?

Tags: arm, qemu

I get Disk image on http://dist.gem5.org/dist/current/arm/disks/linaro-minimal-aarch64.img.bz2
and I build linux-5.8.1 kernel myself.

And I try to run qemu vm with this command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
        -machine virt \
        -cpu max \
        -boot c -m 2049M -drive format=raw,file=$IMAGEPATH \
        -kernel $KERNELPATH/arch/boot/Image \
        -append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0,115200 acpi=off nokaslr" \
        --serial stdio
```

But I can see only qemu monitor, not guest virtual machine. How can I control guest with this situation?
I try `$KERNELPATH/vmlinux` and `$KERNELPATH/arch/boot/Image.gz` but also only qemu monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what each flags does, but this command solve my problem. I write here for someone who has same problem as mine.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M virt                 \
    -cpu max                \
    -nographic              \
    -smp $(SMP)             \
    -kernel $(KERNEL_IMG)   \
    -m 4G                   \
    -netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=tcp::$(SSHFWD)-:22     \
    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet                  \
    -drive file=$(ROOTFS_DIR)/ubuntu-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback    \
    -append "rootwait root=/dev/vda2 rw console=ttyAMA0"    \
    -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0
```